# Sequence detector independent of cycle

Tags: system-verilog

How do you code a FSM that can detect 1010, but can stay '1' or '0' for multiple cycles. Typical FSMs detect 1010 patterns for consecutive clock cycles. Is it possible to use the same /similar FSM to detect 1010 patterns even though '1' can stay '1' for two cycles and '0'can stay '0' for two cycles ...

Comment: You really should be showing some code. As it stands the question does not make too much sense to me. An example showing the input sequence and output sequences you want might go a long way to explain it.

Answer (score -1):

While, in principle, you can use a very similar sequence detecting FSM for detecting sequences in which each symbol stays on the line for two or more cycles rather than one, this only works if the symbol is on the line for a fixed period. For example, if either a 1 or 0 is consider a sequence character if it stays on the line for two cycles, then either you can clock your FSM using a divided clock so its half the frequency or expanding your sequence to 11001100 would solve your problem (for detecting 1010). This works for any sequence in which you define a value of 1 or 0 over a fixed number of cycles, ie all values will be held for a known period of time.

If, however, you want to detect the sequence with values defined over a variable number of cycles, this is not really possible. To say you have found the sequence 1010 is to say the line became one, then zero, then one, then zero. If the definition of the line becoming one is that it is one for one or more cycles, then it becomes impossible to determine if seeing 1 in the first cycle and then 1 in the second cycle is a single one or two ones. For example, take the short sequence below:

11001100110000

In the fixed case, with 1 symbol every clock (which with you are familiar), the sequence is just how it reads: 11001100110000. In the case I described above with a fixed period of 1 symbol every two clocks, the sequence is now 1010100. However, if we say that a symbol for the sequence can be a variable number of clocks, that sequence above can be resolved to any number of sequences:
101010
1101010,
1001010,
1011010,
1010010,
1010110,
1010100,
10101000,
101010000,
11001010,
11011010,
11010010,
...,
11001100110000.

Without defining a what a symbol is, it becomes difficult to create an FSM as any input sequence can quick permute into a very large number of possible sequences. It thus becomes impossible to determine sender intent without more information. Either you need another signal to determine when to sample the line or some other what of distinguishing what the interpretation is suppose to be.

If you do want to make an FSM can determines if any of these permutations matches a given sequence, then you can do that but boiling your sequence down to the minimum requires. In our example sequence above (11001100110000), if we wanted to see if that sequence CAN be interpreted as your sequence (1010), we can find the needed elements to make a possibly sequence 1010 by seeing that you have to see 1 for some time (ie, see at least one 1), then 0 for some time (at least one 0), then 1 for some time (at least one 1), then 0 for some time (at least one 0). Note that any alternating line would thus match.

In the case of an non-alternating sequence like 11001, we could look at the line sequence (1100110011000) looking for at least 2 ones, then at least 2 zeroes, then at least 1 one. In the FSMs youre familiar with, seeing the pattern 11000 would result in a return arc back to start, ie the pattern 11001 was not seen. However, in the variable length case, the FSM would stay in the "seen 1100" state as 11000 could be interpreted as 1100.

Im not sure how useful this would be as the intended sequence is sent on the line cannot be determined due to the problem I mentioned, you cannot determine what constitutes a symbol.